# Angular - Copy array to modeled array

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, mapping

I need to make a custom array from an array receiving from an API Rest. I receive this model :

```
export interface AreaEstadistica {
  id_area_estadistica: String;
  nombre: String;      
  id_distrito: String;
  calculos_estadisticos_pt: Array<CalculoEstadistico>;
}

export interface CalculoEstadistico {
  uso: string;
  valor_tipo: number;
  valor_estandar: number;
}
```

And i want to make an array with the same fields, because in the object `CalculoEstadistico` I can receive so much information, and i need the 'header' for any register in `CalculoEstadistico`, something like this:

```
export interface AreaEstadistica2 {
  id_area_estadistica: String; //Header from this
  nombre: String;
  id_distrito: String;// To this
  uso: string;      
  valor_tipo: number;
  valor_estandar: number;
}
```

The service in Angular 5 :

```
getAreasEstadisticas(): Observable<AreaEstadistica[]> {
    let url: string = this.urlEstadisticas;   
    console.log('URL' + url);
    return this._http.get<AreaEstadistica[]>(url);
  }
```

I tried it by using a `map` in the component:

```
    areas: AreaEstadistica[] = [];
    areas2: AreaEstadistica2[] = [];
//...

getAreas() {
    this._EstadisticasService
      .getAreasEstadisticas()
      .subscribe(
        res => {
          this.areas = res;
          this.transformArray();
        },
        err => {
          console.log(err);
          alert('error');
        }
      );
  }
transformArray(){
    this.areas.map(item => {
            return {
               id_area_estadistica: item.id_area_estadistica,
               nombre: item.nombre,           
               id_distrito: item.id_distrito,
               aa_ponencia_total: item.aa_ponencia_total,
               uso: item.calculos_estadisticos_pt[i].uso,                    
               valor_estandar: item.calculos_estadisticos_pt[i].valor_estandar,
               valor_tipo: item.calculos_estadisticos_pt[i].valor_tipo
            };
        }).forEach(item => this.areas2.push(item));
}
```

But this code don't work. One of the errors:

> src/app/estadisticas/estadisticas.component.ts(129,57): error TS2304:
>   Cannot find name 'i'.

Any ideas? I don't know how to access to the fields in the object `CalculoEstadistico` to map them:

```
uso: item.calculos_estadisticos_pt[i].uso,                    
valor_estandar: item.calculos_estadisticos_pt[i].valor_estandar,
valor_tipo: item.calculos_estadisticos_pt[i].valor_tipo
```

Is there a way to copy a nested model array to another model array? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You use index *i* that does not exists:

```
valor_tipo: item.calculos_estadisticos_pt[i].valor_tipo
```

Comment: And how can I access to the fields in the object? ` uso: item.calculos_estadisticos_pt[i].uso,`

Comment: calculos_estadisticos_pt is a array. Value of i depends on which element of calculos_estadisticos_pt do you want to assign to valor_tipo

Comment: And is there a way to copy a nested model array to another model array?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to add fields of a nested array in the main array.
e.g

```
arry1 = {
  name: 'suhel',
  id: 1,
  contact : {
    email: 'email',
    number: '123'
  }
}
```

Now iterate the nested array like this

```
for(let key of Object.keys(arry1.contact)) {
  arry1[key] = arry1.contact[key];
}
```

Now delete the contact field if you want

```
delete arry1["contact"];
```

Then final result will be like this

```
arry1 = {
  email: "email"
  id: 1
  name: "suhel"
  number: "123"
}
```

Comment: Hmm, it gives me compile error because don't recognize areas.calculos_estadisticos_pt  :/. And idk if u mean 'concat' instead of contact

for(let key of Object.keys(areas.calculos_estadisticos_pt )) {
  areas[key] = areas.calculos_estadisticos_pt[key];
}